# Making `git status` ignore whitespace changes

Tags: git, whitespace, removing-whitespace, git-status

`git status` shows me, that few files are modified. But when I execute `git diff` with any of parameters below, it's empty.

```
   --ignore-space-at-eol
       Ignore changes in whitespace at EOL.

   -b, --ignore-space-change
       Ignore changes in amount of whitespace. This ignores whitespace at line end, and considers all other sequences of one or more whitespace characters to be equivalent.

   -w, --ignore-all-space
       Ignore whitespace when comparing lines. This ignores differences even if one line has whitespace where the other line has none.
```

I've tried `git checkout .` to reset this changes, but it doesn't help. How can I either rollback this files to original state (so they won't be "modified" anymore) or make `git status` ignore whitespace changes permanently?

`git reset --hard` is also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to discard all the changes in the current git repo

use, `git checkout -- .`

Do check the files which needs to be cleaned if any using `git clean -n` for untracked files.

Note:

Be Very careful with `git reset --hard`, this removes all the files which are not committed. Changes will be lost permanently(cannot be reverted).

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: @MohammedRafeeq Let me know if "How can I either rollback this files to original state (so they won't be "modified" anymore)"  question asked above is not answered.

Answer (score 2):

5 years late to the party, but...

I get this quite often when exporting Drupal 8 configs (`drush cex`). I'll run `git stash save` immediately followed by `git stash pop`. `git status` then only reports files with actual changes.